# Why the web workers files have to be inside my public folder of the React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, web-worker

I've ran into a problem trying to understand how web workers might be used inside React apps:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at worker.js:1:1)
I did a research on StackOverflow and found out that this problem could be solved just by moving the web worker file to the public folder of my React app. Can someone explain why did it worked?

This works:

[image: Working]

This doesn't work and gives error:

> (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at worker.js:1:1))

[image: Not Working]

The code (I don't think it matters but anyway):

```
//App.js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  console.log("hey");
  const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
  return <div>App</div>;
};

export default App;
```

```
//worker.js
console.log("work");
```

Comment: That syntax error means that your server is returning an error page, because the attempted fetch of your script failed. The worker scripts need to be accessible from web clients.

Comment: @Pointy didn't get your point, could you please elaborate

Comment: @JayantSharma the browser has to be able to use HTTP GET requests to load worker scripts, so they have to be public.

Comment: @Pointy But I haven't seen any GET request for the worker scrips in the network calls. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works for me by giving relative path of the worker file:

```
const worker = new Worker("./worker3.js") // Unexpected token '<' (at worker3.js:1:1) 
const worker = new Worker("src/components/web-worker/worker3.js") // works
```

or you can import your worker script by exporting it as Blob

Refer: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/web-worker-reactjs-2sswe?file=%2Fsrc%2Fworker.js